# Aggregate addfield pipeline not getting corresponding values

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

For some reason, it seems like my code wont give me the values of `progress` and `completed` as intended to.

currently running the query,, it would result in:

```
[{  
   badgeid:4,
   progress:44,
   "name":"x1",
   "progress":0,
   "completed":false,
   "userid":"5c8522a96bcca9268c0753fe"
},
{  
   "badgeid":5,
   "progress":44,
   "name":"x2",
   "completed":false,
   "userid":"5c8522a96bcca9268c0753fe"
}

]
```

For some reason, it will not give the corresponding progress value and completed value to the corresponding achievement.

i have determined when the `achievement_users` `badgeid 5` document, with `completed` attribute of `true`, would return all the documents to have `completed true`, instead of acually give the correct values to the individual documents.

I would like the progress to be linked to the corresponding `bageid` with correct value, and same with completed, if user dont have a record with the badgeid in achievement_users the `completed` would be `false`, else it would be collected from the corresponding one.

How would i achieve this?

Current achievement_users database:

```
{  
   badgeid:5,
   progress:44,
   completed:true,
   userid:"5c8522a96bcca9268c0753fe"
}
```

Current achievements database:

```
[  
   {  
      "badgeid":4,
      "name":"xx1",
      "max":100,
   },
   {  
      "_id":"5c94c032758c8a2044404995",
      "badgeid":5,
      "name":"xx2",
      "max":1,
   }

   ]
```

Here is my aggregate:

```
    achivementUsers.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "userid": '' +userid + '' }},
    { "$lookup": {
            "from": "achievements",
            "let": { "badgeid": "$badgeid", "progress": "$progress", "userid": "$userid", "completed":"$completed" },
            "pipeline": [
                { "$addFields": {
                        "progress": { "$cond": [{ "$eq": ["$badgeid", "$badgeid"] }, "$$progress", 0] },
                        "completed": { "$cond": [{ "$eq": ["$badgeid", "$$badgeid"] }, true, false] },
                        "userid": "$$userid",
                    }}
            ],
            "as": "inventory_docs"
        }},
    { "$unwind": "$inventory_docs" },
    { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$inventory_docs" }}
]).then(function (response) {
```

edit:

wanted output:

```
[{  
   badgeid:4,
   progress:0,
   "name":"x1",
   "progress":0,
   "completed":false,
   "userid":"5c8522a96bcca9268c0753fe"
},
{  
   "badgeid":5,
   "progress":44,
   "name":"x2",
   "completed":true,
   "userid":"5c8522a96bcca9268c0753fe"
}

]
```

Comment: I think your condition should be `"completed": { "$cond": [{ "$eq": ["$badgeid", "$$badgeid"] }, true, false] }`

Comment: seems correct, what about progress value?

Comment: I believe it's working

Comment: now its a value of 44 on both rows after my latest test. while it should only be on one.

Comment: No condition couldn't fail. It should work. No clues for me here.

Comment: hmm, really weird, i must have missed something.